# Python - Issues with storing user editable strings into a list

Tags: python, string

I'm having trouble creating a very simple program that allows a user to store and edit strings, viewed in a list format (I started programming just a few weeks ago).  Whenever I execute the program, the user input doesn't edit the strings.  Here is my code, and below that is what the program currently does, and what I intend it to do once its patched up (mind you, im getting no errors).

```
Code:

#Program that stores up to 5 strings

def main():
    line1="hello"
    line2=""
    line3=""
    line4=""
    line5=""
    print("[1]"+line1)
    print("[2]"+line2)
    print("[3]"+line3)
    print("[4]"+line4)
    print("[5]"+line5)
    print("")
    print("Which line would you like to edit?")
    lineChoice=''
    while lineChoice not in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):
        lineChoice=input("> ")
    if lineChoice=="1":
        print("You are now editing Line 1.")
        line1=input("> ")
        main()
    if lineChoice=="2":
        print("You are now editing Line 2.")
        line2=input("> ")
        main()
    if lineChoice=="3":
        print("You are now editing Line 3.")
        line3=input("> ")
        main()
    if lineChoice=="4":
        print("You are now editing Line 4.")
        line4=input("> ")
        main()
    if lineChoice=="5":
        print("You are now editing Line 5.")
        line5=input("> ")
        main()

main()
```

Here is what my program does.

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
[1]hello
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]

Which line would you like to edit?
> 1
You are now editing Line 1.
> hello world
[1]hello
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]

Which line would you like to edit?
>
```

Here is what I intend to have my program do.

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
[1]hello
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]

Which line would you like to edit?
> 1
You are now editing Line 1.
> hello world
[1]hello world
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]

Which line would you like to edit?
>
```

If I need to provide any more information, I will be willing to.

- Jacob Densmore

Comment: 1. You're (re)defining line1,2,3,4,5 every time you enter main() ; 2. You're not using a list, you're just using a bunch of similarly named strings; 3. you could reduce all those calls to `main` that are nested into `if` statements into a single call at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually because you are recursively calling `main` so each time your variables are reset. What you need to do is replace a recursive call to `main` with a `while` loop. Changing your code as little as possible, it would look like this (assuming you are on 3.x and using `input` for that reason):

```
def main():
    line1="hello"
    line2=""
    line3=""
    line4=""
    line5=""
    while True:
        print("[1]"+line1)
        print("[2]"+line2)
        print("[3]"+line3)
        print("[4]"+line4)
        print("[5]"+line5)
        print("")
        print("Which line would you like to edit?")
        lineChoice=''
        while lineChoice not in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):
            lineChoice=input("> ")
        if lineChoice=="1":
            print("You are now editing Line 1.")
            line1=input("> ")
        if lineChoice=="2":
            print("You are now editing Line 2.")
            line2=input("> ")
        if lineChoice=="3":
            print("You are now editing Line 3.")
            line3=input("> ")
        if lineChoice=="4":
            print("You are now editing Line 4.")
            line4=input("> ")
        if lineChoice=="5":
            print("You are now editing Line 5.")
            line5=input("> ")

main()
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks.  Im surprised that I didn't see that issue.